# Shuffling cards in a repeater using images from a dataset in Wix

Tags: javascript, shuffle, velo

I am creating a page on Wix where I have a repeater that only brings 3 items from my dataset at a time when clicking on the shuffling button (there are 22 cards in the dataset) that is supposed to shuffle and bring different combinations.

**What I expect:**
Click on the button, then it brings 3 random cards (that are images of cards in my data set) from a deck of 22 cards.

**What is happening:**
It is bringing the same few combinations of cards and it is not actually random and some cards never shows up.

Here is my code:

```
export function button7_click(event) {

// clear any filters in the dataset
$w("#dynamicDataset").setFilter( wixData.filter() );

// get size of collection that is connected to the dataset
let count = $w("#dynamicDataset").getTotalCount();

// get random number using the size as the maximum
let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * count-1);

// set the current item index of the dataset
$w("#dynamicDataset").setCurrentItemIndex(idx);
}
```

What can I do to bring really random spread of 3 cards?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's `Math.random()` function is fast, but it has issues. First, it's not seedable, second, its randomness leaves little to be desired. According to the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox), the existence of duplicate values ​​does not mean that they are random. Although there are many ways to change the Random number pattern in JavaScript, here are three different methods adopted by the community:

1. [Seedable Random Number Generator Algorithm](http://davidbau.com/archives/2010/01/30/random_seeds_coded_hints_and_quintillions.html): This algorithm allows to generate a seedable random number generator in Javascript that you can tweak to generate a deterministic random number sequence. Browsers do not provide a built-in way to seed `Math.random()`, so this solution is useful both when you need a completely predictable repeatable pseudo-random sequence and when you need a robust seed that is much more unpredictable than your browser's.
2. [Mersenne Twister](https://gist.github.com/banksean/300494): This algorithm compensates for not being allowed to specify an initial value for `Math.random()`.
3. [Alea](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alea), [PRNG Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator): A Pseudo-Random Number Generator (PRNG) is an algorithm for generating a sequence of numbers whose properties approximate those of sequences of random numbers. The Alea package implements this algorithm.